# Prepared statement - using a function as part of the where clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I am working with a Java prepared statement that gets data from an Oracle database. Due to some performance problems, the query uses a "virtual column" as an index.

The query looks like this:

```
String status = "processed";
String customerId = 123;
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT trans_id FROM trans WHERE status = " + status + " AND FN_GET_CUST_ID(trans.trans_id) = " + customerId;

Connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  ps.execute();
  ...
} catch (...)
```

This does not work. Having the function as part of the where clause causes a SQLException. I am aware of CallableStatement, and know I could use that first and then concatenate the results. However, this table uses FN_GET_CUST_ID(trans_id) as part of it's index. Is there a way to use a prepared statement with a database function as a query parameter?

Comment: Status processed should be quoted. Maybe that's what causing your exception, no?

Comment: Having a function in the WHERE clause should work, your problem probably lies elsewhere. Could you post the error code and message (SQLException.getErrorCode) ? Does the query actually work in SQL*Plus?

Comment: Sorry, the example I posted was not copied verbatim. I tried to trim it down to remove a lot of the excess non-essential stuff. The missing quotes is not the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Never concatenate arguments for the SQL into the String. Always use placeholders (`?`) and `setXxx(column, value);`.
2. You'll get the same error if you'd run the SQL in a your favorite DB tool. The problem is that Oracle can't use the function for some reason. What error code do you get?

Comment: The problem was that the function didn't have public execute privileges. #2 in Aaron's comment "The problem is that Oracle can't use the function for some reason." is what eventually led me to find the problem, so giving credit to him.

Answer (score 1):

If Customer ID is numeric keep in int not in String. Then try doing the following:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT trans_id FROM trans WHERE status = ? AND FN_GET_CUST_ID(trans.trans_id) = ?"; 

ps = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
ps.setString(1, status);
ps.setInt(2, customerId);
ps.execute();
```

Besides other benefits of prepared statement you won't have to remember about string quotations (this causes your error most likely) and escaping of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance, the query seems to be incorrect. You are missing an apostrophe before and after the usage of `status` variable (assuming that status is a varchar column).

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT trans_id FROM trans 
WHERE status = '" + status + "' AND FN_GET_CUST_ID(trans.trans_id) = " + customerId;
```

EDIT: I am not from java background. However, as @Aron has said, it is better to use placeholders & then use some method to set values for parameters to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: That's correct as I pointed out in my first comment to the question. However probably it's even better to use the placeholders in the queryas Aaron mentioned - otherwise there is no benefit from usinf PreparedStatement.